# Efficient downsampling for post-processing effects in opengl 3.3

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I understand the idea behind the bloom/glow effect: we downsample the texture to keep our convolution kernels small.  Now that I am trying to implement it, I am not quite sure which road I should take.

My first idea was to **use `glGenerateMipMap`** to do the downsampling.  However, I cannot tell it to stop after, say, 4 steps.  It's a bit of a black box for me, and for all I know, it may generate 10 images to sample my screen from 1024*768 down to 1*1.  Maybe these last steps are cheap because everything is so small already, but maybe they are not.

I googled around and found that many people were relying on FBOs rather than `glGenerateMipMap`.  I am familiar with FBOs since I use deferred lighting.  My second idea is to simply **render a 'quad' with a linear sampler into a smaller texture**.  I would do that four times in a row, halving width and height each time.  However, I found that [some people preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534815/glsl-330-down-sample-texture) using their **own fragment shader for downsampling rather than relying on `GL_LINEAR`** and I wonder why; maybe it is faster?

What would be a way to quickly downsample my full-screen texture 4 times in a row, keeping each version?  I have no need for fancy edge-preserving sampling algorithms as I am going to blur everything anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> we downsample the texture to keep our convolution kernels small.

Or you simply render the bloom/glow layer at a smaller resolution in the first place. This saves both fillrate and you don't have to minify afterwards.

> My second idea is to simply render a 'quad' with a linear sampler into a smaller texture.

This is no downsampling it all. It's linear interpolation between sampling points and may create artifacts.

Comment: "*the bloom/glow layer*" That assumes that there is a "layer" there, rather than just the HDR image that you rendered, which you want to apply bloom to.

Comment: Indeed I don't have a layer for the glowing bits, just one HDR image.
What kind of artifacts should I expect from rendering into a smaller texture?

Comment: @Niriel: The typical artifact that appear if the sampled data containes higher frequencies than half the subsampling frequency. That's why you apply the bluring kernel in the first place: It acts as a lowpass filter so that subsampling will not create Moiree artifacts or aliasing (aliasing in the signal theory sense, not in the "blocky edges" sense, although mathematically both effects are related).

Comment: Duh, of course!  My brain derped.  This is exactly the reason why we use mipmap, I got so used to them I almost forgot that the averaging was not part of the linear sampler.  I'm happy you set my brain back on track.  So, if I call `glTexParameter(GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL)` to get 4 levels, and then I generate the mipmaps, I'll get exactly the 4 images I want?

Comment: @Niriel: Indeed this is the case. You can control which levels glGenerateMimap creates using the texture level parameters.